# Extract field session id in a string

Tags: python

I need to extract the `sessionID` from a return rest:

```
Example: !!br.com.return.test.rest.schema.CtresponseResp {error: null, sessionID: c1d840fd-fc2a-4e04-8c21-ffb5a9a58a13}
```

I only need the `c1d840fd-fc2a-4e04-8c21-ffb5a9a58a13`.

Comment: I'm not down voting, but you should definitely look around the site (just click on help -- "?") and figure out how to ask a question.  And start by showing us what you've tried - that will help a lot. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\w+\d.+[^\W]')
s = '!!br.com.return.test.rest.schema.CtresponseResp {error: null, sessionID: c1d840fd-fc2a-4e04-8c21-ffb5a9a58a13}'
print(''.join(p.findall(s)))
```

Output:

```
c1d840fd-fc2a-4e04-8c21-ffb5a9a58a13
```

Comment: @JersonLuizdePaulaJunior I edited the answer so you get just the string, without the ''.